# C: my_strstr returning Needle when Needle is not found in Haystack

Tags: c, string, pointers, traversal, pointer-arithmetic

My first stack overflow question, so I hope it is well formed.

I've made a simple function which emulates strstr:

```
char *my_strstr(char *haystack, char *needle)
{
   int i;

   if (!needle || !*needle)
       return (haystack); // if s2 is empty
   while (*haystack != '\0')
   {
    i = 0;
    while (*haystack != *needle && *haystack != '\0')
        haystack++;
    while (haystack[i] == needle[i] && haystack[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    if (needle[i] == '\0')
        return (haystack);
    haystack++;
   }
    return  (0);
}
```

To test it, I have the following main:

```
int     main(void)
{
    char *haystack = "Stacy Lives Next Door Fool";
    char *needle = "Stb";
    char *ptr;

    ptr = my_strstr(haystack, needle);
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    return (0); 
 }
```

When I compile this, it works in every scenario except when needle is not found at all in haystack. In fact, when that is the case "Stb" - the value of needle - shows up on the screen. Could someone explain to me why this is so? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `if (!s2)` --> `if (!s2 || !*s2)` BTW: please use descriptive names instead op a1 and a2 (gnu uses *haystack* and *needle* )

Comment: `s1++;` : `s1` already became  `'\0'`, And pass by the `++`

Comment: @wildplasser Good thinking to have both scenarios where the pointer and string are NULL or empty. I have updated the question using haystack and needle terminology.

Comment: Please don't update the question. [and: you are mixing pointer- and array semantics. Why are you testing against `'\0'` and `0` and without any comparison?]

Comment: @wildplasser Could you describe in more detail what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote the same code [here](http://ideone.com/c8RIYj). Do not `return (0)` for a `char *` in your `my_strstr`, it works as expected for your example

Comment: Thank you for posting your code however, I do not get the expected results when compiling what you've written. In fact, I get a new line, "In this loop" and finally the value of the needle, "Stb". I tried to follow your line of thinking and created a NULL pointer just to return in case of no match. But "Stb" still appeared.

Comment: when i run the same code in that same IDE, it is printing "dpes not exist"

Comment: I wouldn't think for such a question it'd be relevant but seeing our contrast in results, I'm compiling this on x86_64_apple-darwin 13.4.0

Comment: i wouldn't think it is relevant either. Sorry, couldn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input @user1455116, however your code produced a similar error on my machine. In order to make it functional, I added a condition after the second while loop:

```
if (*str == '\0')
     return (0);
```

If we've gone through the whole string, of course there's no match.

Comment: What `str` do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone explain to me why this is so?

The behavior of your program is undefined, since it passes the null pointer `ptr` returned from `my_strstr()` to `printf()`. Depending on the implementation, a variety of things can happen, including printing of `(null)`, a `Segmentation fault`, and printing of some random memory content, which seems to be your case. One might be able to explain this in detail by examining the assembler code generated. But of course the error has to be corrected, e. g. by replacing your

```
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

with

```
    printf("%s\n", ptr ? ptr : "needle is not found at all in haystack");
```